# How to create image from .ts video file in android?

Tags: java, android, bitmap, mediametadataretriever

I m getting this error " getFrameAtTime: videoFrame is a NULL pointer " Below is my code. Any suggestion to fix this error

```
 ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.picutre);

  try {

       MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
       retriever.setDataSource("/storage/sdcard0/download/videos/kamran.ts");
       Bitmap bMap = retriever.getFrameAtTime(0,MediaMetadataRetriever.OPTION_CLOSEST_SYNC);

       img.setImageBitmap(bMap);

    }
    catch(Exception e){
       Log.d("File","Error Creating image",e);
    }
```

I have also tried these two methods but getting the same error message (getFrameAtTime: videoFrame is a NULL pointer)

```
Bitmap bMap = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail("/storage/sdcard0/download/videos/kamran.ts", MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND);


Bitmap bMap = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail("/storage/sdcard0/download/videos/kamran.ts", Thumbnails.FULL_SCREEN_KIND);
```